# Install apache 2.4.6 on Ubuntu manually

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

Currently I am trying to install apache web server in an Ubuntu server by hand. The package I'm downloading is this: http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.6-2ubuntu2.debian.tar.gz but the package uncompresses (tar -xf Route+file) and it doesn´t let me do anything else to install it (use ./configure or sudo make)

We due to requirements in migrations cant just add a route in the configuration file and make the easy installation (we are trying to have 2 apache installations on our server, in case we need to uninstall this one).

Could you please indicate what is missing or where am I wrong? thank you

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? Is there a reason you're not using `apt-get`?

Comment: This belongs on http://askubuntu.com/